# asp.net Optimization bundler {version} feature doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have to following code in my *Bundle.Config*:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js/jquery")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                     "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-{version}.js",
                     "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

My *Package.config* file contains the following:

```
...
<package id="jQuery" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net45" />
...
```

My *_Layout.cshtml* contains the following code:

```
<head>
...
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js/jquery")
...
</head>
```

And I have these two files in my Scripts folder: *"jquery-1.7.1.js"* + *"jquery-1.9.1.js"*

I would expect only the file *"jquery-1.9.1.js"* would be downloaded. But in debug mode I see both *"jquery-1.7.1.js"* + *"jquery-1.9.1.js"* are getting downloaded. Harder to check but it could be that the problem occures in release mode as well.

Changing the include phrase to the exact version (e.g. 1.9.1), or deleting the old version from the folder, solves the problem, but of course it's not the desired solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The {version} uses regex (\d+(?:.\d+){1,3}) to id the js files to add.  It is really only there to prevent you having to update your bundle configuration every time you update your js file versions.  If you have multiple versions of the same js file in the same folder, then it will pull all these in.

HTH.